# Please explain the working of the following code in Python 2. What is the use of end? Also __future__ library

Tags: python, integer, python-2.x

```
from __future__ import print_function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input())
    for n in range(n):
        print(((n)+1),end='')
```

Also why can't we use the following one:

```
for n in range(n):
    print n,
```

Comment: end refers to the string terminator to be printed, by default its "\n".

Comment: Why can't you use `for n in range(n): print n`? It works (but not if you run `from __future__ import print_function` first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Starting at the top**:

In Python 2.x, `print` was a statement, not a function, and as such had certain limitations. As Python 3 evolved, the `print()` function was created. This function was so useful, that the Python 2.x folks included a means to add the `print()` function to Python 2.7, by using the **from __future__ import print_function** capability (NOTE: you need the double underscores).

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

One of the features included in the `print()` function was the ability to include strings to separate multiple values (`sep=' '` is the default) and to include strings to append to the end of a printed value (`end='\n'` is the default).

In this case, `end=''` puts an empty string at the end of the printed value.

```
if name == 'main': 
    n = int(raw_input()) 
    for n in range(n): 
        print(((n)+1),end='')
```

**Next:**

Once you import the `print()` function, that essentially overrides the `print` statement, which is why you can't use it any more.

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> for n in range(7):
...    print n,
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print n,
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```